# エクセルVBAで条件を満たすもののうち最小のものを取得する

Tags: vba, excel

エクセルで次のような表がシートにあったとします。

| グループ | 値 |
| --- | --- |
| A | 3 |
| A | 4 |
| A | 5 |
| B | 4 |
| B | 7 |
| B | 8 |

この時、SQLで言う所の

```
select MIN(値) 
from table
where グループ='A'
```

のようなことをエクセルVBAでやりたいのですが、どのようなコードを組めばよいでしょうか？
よろしくお願いします。

Comment: エクセル関数でもできると思いますが、「エクセルVBAでやりたい」理由は何でしょうか？データ（表）の範囲が固定されていないとかでしょうか？

Comment: エクセルVBAの処理の流れの中でこの計算が使いたかったのですが、そんなに不自然ですか？for文でデータを回してそれに対してこの計算をしたい。ちなみにエクセル関数ではどうやるのでしょうか？

Comment: 「そんなに不自然ですか？」については、「エクセルVBAの処理の流れの中でこの計算が使いたかった」と質問に書いてないので、質問の内容であればVBAを使うまでもないのではないでしょうか？と思ったので最初のコメントを投稿いたしました。

Comment: 「ちなみにエクセル関数ではどうやるのでしょうか？」ですが、お使いのExcelのバージョンは何でしょうか？バージョンによっては使える関数に違いがあります。”エクセル グループ 最小値”などでネット検索すれば方法が出てきますのでお使いのExcelのバージョンに合った方法を確認されると良いかと思います。関数ではありませんがピボットテーブルを使っても良いかもしれません。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Officeのバージョンが365または2019なら、MinIfs関数を使えばいいでしょう。

その表がA1から始まっているとして、

```
Public Sub Sample()
    Dim tbl As Range
    Set tbl = Cells(1).CurrentRegion
    
    Dim minValue
    minValue = WorksheetFunction.MinIfs(tbl.Columns(2), tbl.Columns(1), "A")
    MsgBox "グループAの最小値: " & minValue
End Sub
```

MinIfs関数が使えないバージョンならループで最小値を取得するといいでしょう。

```
Public Sub Sample2()
    Dim tbl As Range
    Set tbl = Cells(1).CurrentRegion
    
    Dim minValue, R As Range
    For Each R In tbl.Rows
        If R.Cells(1) = "A" Then
            If R.Cells(2) < minValue Or IsEmpty(minValue) Then
                minValue = R.Cells(2)
            End If
        End If
    Next
    MsgBox "グループAの最小値: " & minValue
End Sub
```